# Facebook graph api deprecation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a old rubygem for facebook graph api, that do request structured as shown below:

```
get("/page-id/insights/page_impressions/day")
```

now this unversioned request work's but are not specified in the docs. The period should be passed as a argument(?period=day) and not sure if will work in the future...

The 1.0 API will be deprecated and I don't know if have to migrate de gem to use the 2.1 structure for request. Anyone knows something about it?